# Cannot read property 'y' of undefined - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm getting this weird error when I try to assign variables in react's `useEffect` Hook.

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'y' of undefined

Here is my code for this file and it's a very basic file:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import '../../node_modules/react-vis/dist/style.css';
import {XYPlot, LineSeries, VerticalGridLines, 
    HorizontalGridLines, XAxis, YAxis,
    makeWidthFlexible, MarkSeries} from 'react-vis';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
      maxWidth: '100%',
      border: '2px solid black',
      'border-radius': '10px'
    },
    graphDimensions: {
        width:'100%'
    }
}));

function StockChartCard(props){
    const classes = useStyles();

    const [strokeColor, setstrokeColor] = useState('red');
    const [data, setdata] = useState([
        {x: 0, y: 8},
        {x: 1, y: 5},
        {x: 2, y: 4},
        {x: 3, y: 9},
        {x: 4, y: 1},
        {x: 5, y: 7},
        {x: 6, y: 6},
        {x: 7, y: 3},
        {x: 8, y: 2},
        {x: 9, y: 0},
        {x: 10, y: 1},
        {x: 11, y: 5},
        {x: 12, y: 4},
        {x: 13, y: 9},
        {x: 14, y: 1},
        {x: 15, y: 7},
        {x: 16, y: 6},
        {x: 17, y: 3},
        {x: 18, y: 2},
        {x: 19, y: 0},
        {x: 20, y: 1}
    ]);
    const [openBenchmarkData, setopenBenchmarkData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getStockData = async () => {
    
            console.log(data[0].y);
        
            const openPrice = data[0].y;
            const currentPrice = data[-1].y;

            if(currentPrice < openPrice){
                setstrokeColor('red')
            }
            else{
                setstrokeColor('green')
            }
        
            let benchmarkSetData = [];
            data.forEach(element => {
                const xVal = element.x;
                const dataPoint = {x: xVal, y: openPrice};
                benchmarkSetData.push(dataPoint);
            });
            setopenBenchmarkData(...openBenchmarkData, benchmarkSetData);
        }
        getStockData();
    }, [])

    return (
        <Container className={classes.root}>
            {props.quoteTicker}
                {data.length > 0 && openBenchmarkData.length > 0
                ?   (
                    <XYPlot width={650} height={300}>
                        <LineSeries animation={'noWobble'} data={data} color={strokeColor} />
                        <LineSeries data={openBenchmarkData} strokeDasharray={[1,2]}/>
                    </XYPlot>
                )
                : null
                }
        </Container>
      );
}

export default StockChartCard;
```

It's saying `data[0]` and `data[-1]` are `undefined` but that print statement shows that the array is not `null` and has the values that i set it too. It's not a state issue because if I set data as just a constant in the file, it still doesn't work... any help is appreciated, getting killed mentally over this dumb error.

Comment: How do you have an index at -1 in an array?

Comment: That would be the last element of the array

Comment: Are you sure about that? That is not how arrays work.

Comment: omg... im such a bum. I fixed it lol. There is somewhere where that works no? I used that all the time for something...

Comment: I think jQuery used to have -1 as index for last item.

Comment: Maybe in python? Otherwise, you'll have to go with `array.slice(-1)`.

Comment: There are some methods that take negative numbers, not referencing an index.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh it was python that you are able to do that with... damn, thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I m pretty sure -1 wont give you the last value of array what you could do is :

`const currentPrice = data[data.length-1].y;`

Also throw in a `?` optional chaining to prevent undefined when its not available.

`const currentPrice = data[data.length-1]?.y;`